# How to read substrings with varying length

Tags: c, parsing, file-io, fgets

I have a file that has three columns(readings from sensor) of varying length eg.

```
-728 -233 3947
4258 -623 333 
-500 93 -4141 
-491 107 -4136 
-495 94 -4161 
-886 101 -4148 
-2555 1864 -4888
```

I use `fgets` to read the line. But I want to read the first column as x, second as y and third as z. Even if I use blank space as the mark for detecting a new substring, that wont solve my problem, since every line has different length of column digits. Any idea on how to do it? I am pasting a snippet of the code which reads the line from file and tries to print the three substrings as three array elements.

```
char *arr_x, *arr_y, *arr_z;

fp = fopen(filename, mode);
    while(! feof(fp))
    {
        if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) 
            {
                 strncpy(arr_x, str, ' ');
                 strncpy(arr_y, str, ' ');
                 puts(str);

            }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `str` declared?

Comment: Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: str is declared as char str[60]; I just thought of pasting only the logic of reading from file. Thanks Sourav Ghosh!

Comment: suggest : `int x, y, z; ... while(fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL){ sscanf(str, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're on right path, just need to add a bit more tweak. Please have a look at the following algo.

1. Define three arrays, corresponding to `x`, `y` and `z`.
2. Read the whole line.
3. Start tokenizing the line using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) with space as delimiter, as you thought
4. Store the first token in the `i` th index of `x` array, second token in `y` array, third token in `z` array.
5. Continue to next line, increase `i` and keep on storing them until `fgets()` returns NULL.

Also, FWIW,

- Always check the return value of `fopen()` for success before using the returned file pointer.
- see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: I referred to the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm, but that shows "-" as delimiter, but I want space as delimiter.

Comment: @ShankdeepMukerji You can use any delimiter you like. BTW did you check the man page I linked in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for sharing the effect of using while ( !feof (file) ). So for using delim as blank space, should I use " "?

Comment: @ShankdeepMukerji Right.

Comment: if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) 
         {
   token = strtok(str, s);
   while(token != NULL)
   {
   strcpy(ch_x, strtok(NULL, s));
    printf("%s", ch_x);
    strcpy(ch_y, strtok(NULL, s));
    printf("%s", ch_y);
    strcpy(ch_z, strtok(NULL, s));
    printf("%s", ch_z); 
   } p++;
         }
 }                                                                                                                This throws error hello.c:171:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[7]’ from type ‘char *’
     ch_z = strtok(NULL, s);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while(in != '\n') /* while (!fread(&in, 1, 1, p) */
{
     n++;
     arr = (char *) calloc (n, sizeof(char));
     scanf ("%c", &in);
}
```

Sorry couldn't indent on my cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) would be simpler?

I believe this is trusted data so there is no issue with buffer overflows, but if it isn't read the data with fgets (so that you limit the amount of data you read) and then use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) on the string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("read_file_space_delimited.txt", "r");

    if (fp) {        
        int x, y, z;

        while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z) != EOF) {
            printf("Numbers: %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

The file read_file_space_delimited.txt has the data you provided in your question. After compiling and running this program this is the output I get:

```
Numbers: -728 -233 3947
Numbers: 4258 -623 333
Numbers: -500 93 -4141
Numbers: -491 107 -4136
Numbers: -495 94 -4161
Numbers: -886 101 -4148
Numbers: -2555 1864 -4888
```